# Vivado HW manager does not detect my ARTY A7

Tags: fpga, vivado

I installed Vivado ML Standard with all the drivers on Windows 10. As I try to auto or manual connect ARTY A7 in Vivado hardware manager the device doesen't show up.

**What I tried:**

- Changed USB cable,
- Connect device to other PC, where it is working!,
- Reinstalling vivado,
  -Reinstalling cable drivers by running install_drivers_wrapper.bat in vivado installation file nt64,
- Reinstalling cable drivers by the following [instructions](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/1013230?language=en_US) *I know they are for windows 7, but that was out of despair*

**What I found:**
It is stil not working, but in my device manager I only see **USB Serial Converter B**, but as I was reading and saw on othaer computer where it is working, there were **USB Serial Converter A and B**.

Thanks for all the help in advaced.

Comment: If it works on another PC then it's the first PC that is problematic or the installation. I'm not sure that this fits into the rules for a valid EE question on this site.

Comment: @Andyaka I posted it here, since electronic engineer work with FPGAs and some of them might encounter same problem. I managed to solve this problem few minutes after posting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it is working now. I installed [adept](https://digilent.com/reference/software/adept/start?redirect=2#software_downloads) and it detected my device and after that Vivado hardware manager detects it too.